# Accessing command history in QPython console for Android

Tags: readline, read-eval-print-loop, qpython

Is it possible to access previously entered commands in QPython's console/REPL?  Up and down arrows just display escape sequences.  I tried switching the `Terminal type` option between `screen`, `linux`, and `vt100`, but this doesn't seem to help.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911116/qpython-has-no-gnu-readline-capability) didn't specify it was referring to QPython's console, and got an answer that is not relevant.

Comment: If you found my answer satisfactory, please mark it as a solution. :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, it' not possible. The feature hasn't been implemented. But if you can use Python3's syntax instead of Python 2.7, you can use [QPython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpy3&hl=en) app instead where this feature has been implemented.

This is the answers from QPython's support:

> From: QPython Support  Date: Wed, Oct 28, 2015 at
>   1:11 PM Subject: Re: previously entered commands
>
> It doesn't support this now, but we will try to implement the feature
>   in the future for some guys ask the same question.
>
> Thank you for feedback.

Comment: Hm. I'm getting escape sequences when I do up-arrow in a qpython3 console application. So if the command history has been implemented, I'm not sure how to enable it.