# qpython what is the alt button (previous command)

Tags: qpython

Does anyone know how to use/setup the alt button in qpython 2.7
2? I would like to trigger alt+p for previous command. This is on a galaxy s6. There is a special key menu but I do not see anything for alt. Under preferences I see options for control key, fn, or alt sends esc.

Comment: If you found my answer satisfactory, please mark it as a solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly the feature you are trying to access isn't developed in QPython. It is not possible to access previously entered commands in QPython's console. Up and down arrows just display escape sequences asyou can see on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950530/accessing-command-history-in-qpython-console-for-android)

The [QPython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpy3&hl=en) on the other hand has this feature and it seems that the app is better developed. So If you can use python3 syntax instead of python 2.7, I recommend you go for it.

Comment: it would be ideal. retyping commands on a phone isnt as fun as it is on a keyboard lol thank you for verfification.

Comment: I edited my answers to include an alternative. Hope it helps you.